# Cache images during component did mount

Tags: react-native

I am trying to cache images whose url i got from my api so that i dont see my imageview background when the api loads and the images dont

#### I am calling this function inside my `async componentDidMount`

```
 async getData(){

    this.setState({isLoading: true})
    fetch('https://news119.herokuapp.com/getData')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.preload(responseJson.data)
        Toast.show('Refreshed');

        this.setState({
          currentIndex:0,
          dataSource: responseJson.data.sort((a,b)=>a.date<b.date),
        }, async function(){

          this.setState({

            isLoading: false,
            loaded:true,

          })
          AsyncStorage.setItem('ApiData',JSON.stringify(this.state.dataSource))
          AsyncStorage.setItem('POINTER', '0');

        });

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
//the preload function
    async  preload(data){
    console.log(data)
    await FastImage.preload([data.map((item)=>{uri:item.img.data})])
```

Library used is react-native-fast-images.

## I can see the api data in the console but the app crashes without any error screen

If you have a better way to do this(but i need to use the fast images library) please suggest me that too!

Answer (score 1):

'this' inside your promise doesn't mean your components 'this', it means the promise functions 'this'. You need to create a variable before your promise referring to your components 'this' and use that inside the promise to setState.

```
const component = this
fetch('..').then((result) => {component.setState({...})})
```

Comment: This certainly solves the problem but i am still unable to preload the images as they apear blank for some time.Do you have anyidea how to achive this?

Comment: Sorry can't help you there, it might be you're doing something wrong in the preload function or you're using react-native-fast-images wrong. I'm not that well versed in react-native.